# Minecraft bukkit scheduler and procedural instance naming

Tags: instance, scheduler, minecraft, bukkit

This question is probably pretty obvious to any person who knows how to use Bukkit properly, and I'm sorry if I missed a solution in the others, but this is really kicking my ass and I don't know what else to do, the tutorials have been utterly useless. There are really 2 things that I need help doing:

1. I need to learn how to create an indefinite number of instances of an object. I figure it'd be like this:

int num = 0;

```
public void create(){

    String name = chocolate + num;
    Thingy name = new Thingy(); 

}
```

So you see what I'm saying? I need to basically change the name that is given to each new instance so that it doesn't overwrite the last one when created. I swear I've looked everywhere, I've asked my Java professor and I can't get any answers.

2: I need to learn how to use the stupid scheduler, and I can't understand anything so far. Basically, when an event is detected, 2 things are called: one method which activates instantly, and one which needs to be given a 5 second delay, then called. The code is like this:

```
public onEvent(event e){
    Thingy thing = new Thingy();
    thing.method1();
    thing.doOnDelay(method2(), 100 ticks);

}
```

Once again, I apologize if I am not giving too many specifics, but I cannot FOR THE LIFE OF ME find anything about the Bukkit event scheduler that I can understand.

DO NOT leave me links to the Bukkit official tutorials, I cannot understand them at all and it'll be a waste of an answer. I need somebody who can help me, I am a starting plugin writer.

I've had Programming I and II with focus in Java, so many basic things I know, I just need Bukkit-specific help for the second one.

The first one has had me confused since I started programming.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so for the first question I think you want to use a data structure. Depending on what you're doing, there are different data structures to use. A data structure is simply a container that you can use to store many instances of a type of object. The data structures that are available to you are:

- HashMap
- HashSet
- TreeMap
- List
- ArrayList
- Vector

There are more, but these are the big ones. HashMap, HashSet, and TreeMap are all part of the Map class, which is notable for it's speedy operations. To use the hashmap, you instantiate it with `HashMap<KeyThing, ValueThingy> thing = new HashMap<KeyThing, ValueThing>();` then you add elements to it with `thing.put(key, value)`. Thn when you want to get a value out of it, you just use `thing.get(key)` HashMaps use an algorithm that's super fast to get the values, but a consequence of this is that the HashMap doesn't store it's entries in any particular order. Therefore when you want to loop though it with a for loop, it randomly returns it's entries (Not truly random because memory and stuff). Also, it's important to note that you can only have one of each individual key. If you try to put in a key that already exists in the map, it will over-right the value for that key.

The HashSet is like a HashMap but without storing values to go with it. It's a pretty good container if all you need to use it for is to determine if an object is inside it.

The TreeMap is one of the only maps that store it's values in a particular order. You have to provide a Comparator (something that tells if an object is less than another object) so that it knows the order to put the values if it wants them to be in ascending order.

List and ArrayList are not maps. Their elements are put in with a index address. With the List, you have to specify the number of elements you're going to be putting into it. Lists do not change size. ArrayLists are like lists in that each element can be retrieved with `arrayListThing.get(index)` but the ArrayList can change size. You add elements to an ArrayList by `arrayListThing.add(Thing)`.

The Vector is a lot like an ArrayList. It actually functions about the same and I'm not quite sure what the difference between them is.

At any rate, you can use these data structures to store a lot of objects by making a loop. Here's an example with a Vector.

```
Vector<Thing> thing = new Vector<Thing>();
int numberofthings = 100;
for(int i = 0; i < numberofthings; i++) {
    thing.add(new Thing());
}
```

That will give you a vector full of things which you can then iterate through with
    for(Thing elem:thing) {
        thing.dostuff
    }

Ok, now for the second problem. You are correct that you need to use the Bukkit Scheduler. Here is how:

Make a class that extends BukkitRunnable

```
public class RunnableThing extends BukkitRunnable {

    public void run() {
        //what you want to do. You have to make this method.
    }

}
```

Then what you want to do when you want to execute that thing is you make a new BukkitTask object using your RunnableThing

```
BukkitTask example = new RunnableThing().runTaskLater(plugin, ticks)
```

You have to do some math to figure out how many ticks you want. 20 ticks = 1 second. Other than that I think that covers all your questions.

Comment: _Some_ important (to me) differences between Vector and ArrayList: Vectors are synchronized (which makes them thread-safe for modification); when they need more memory, Vectors preallocate double (e.g. 100% more) their prior size while ArrayList preallocates 50% more than the former size.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will be sure to try your suggestions, and the thing on top uses Data Structures. My next class, Programming III, is called "Data Structures and Algorithms", so I'll probably be learning all about them this semester in college. That means if I still don't understand this, I will get it pounded into me in that class. The bukkit thing is also making more sense to me, I'll try it out immediately! Thank you!

Comment: Now here I find myself still confused about the first thing. Is there a way to have a string, say "string0" that is used as the name of a new instance. Maybe it would be like Thing (string0.toName) = new Thing(). Is that possible? I'M JUST SO CONFUSED! Game Maker lets you just call create instance, that instance is known by its id, and you can call create instance over and over and it just gives each new instance a unique numerical "name" that it's known by, and it's no big deal to create hundreds of thousands of instances. Can you tell an object to be named after a string's contents?

Comment: Ok, so you can do that a HashMap<String, Thingy>. The hashmap stores each thing you put into it with a key. The key you use can be anything, but for your case you want to use a String as the key. Make a HashMap with this line of code.
`HashMap<String, Thingy> map = new HashMap<String, Thingy>();`
Then you can store and retrieve all the Thingys you put in with:
`map.put("name1",new Thingy())` and 
`map.get("name1")`
Does that clear things up any?

Comment: Umm... I still find it hard to grasp. It doesn't feel like what I need, though it may be and I'm too stupid to realize it. Perhaps if somebody could explain it (or recommend their favorite resource that explains it) to me in very simple terms, as I am easily confused. It just seems like you should be able to create an instance using the contents of a string as its name in a simple manner. Like this: int count = 0; String namer = "thing" + counter; Thing [here goes namer contents, i.e. thing0, thing1, etc.] = new Thing(); count ++; Is that what HashMap does? I'm a go look up hashmap.

Comment: It looks to me like you're trying to make a bunch of variables, each with a unique variable name so that you use each one by calling that name. Right? You cannot use a string as a variable name, and (as far as I know) you can't dynamically create variable names. You can, however, use a String as a key that points to the object you want in a HashMap. Think of the HashMap as a vending machine. You put each object on the shelves with a unique label (i.e. D5, or F3). When you need one of those objects, you give the vending machine the code that maps to the object you want.

Comment: The HashMap works exactly the same. You make the HashMap, you put the objects into the HashMap with the addresses you want to associate with them, and then you can get any of those objects out by giving an address to the HashMap. The address can be any type (with some conditions). Don't get discouraged, and also don't bother with any explanations on how HashMap works (at least for now). There's a lot of magic that happens that even I don't fully understand. I'm pretty confident that this is what you want though.

Comment: So wait, how does it work in games where you can create infinite instances (at least up to the computer's memory limit)? I doubt they create hashmaps with hundreds of thousands of objects, do they? Like, how does Game Maker create a new instance as needed? Also thanks for the analogy, it helped me understand the hashmap idea a lot. I may use the ArrayList personally though, since I've used it before and sort of know how it works. In fact I've already used it in my plugin for storing a small area of blocks for future reload.

Comment: Well where else would they keep them? Instances of everything have to be stored somewhere or else you lose access to them. You use data structures to store them. Depending on how you're going to need to get the data, you can use different types of data structures. I'm a little confused about your question. You could create millions of instances with a loop, or millions of instances could accumulate over time in response to a player action. When you're thinking of creating instances, what is it that comes to mind?

Comment: When I think of creating instances, I think of being able to create a new instance, say "thingy001" or "thingy9184" you know? Are you saying that in games where there are hundreds of thousands of bullets flying around the air, that before the game started every one of those was pre-created?

Comment: No, they probably were created as a response to an action. Using your example: in your main class you have a list of all the bullets in the game. At the start of the game, that list is empty. Whenever a player pulls a trigger, you make a new bullet instance and store it in the list. Then at each tick of the game you can check where the bullet is and if it is inside another player or out of bounds. If the bullet is out of bounds or in a player, you do the correlated action and remove it from the list. This whole system hinges on the fact that you can detect a player-pull-trigger-event.

Comment: That's cool, so you add an instance to the list, which is sort of like creating a new instance. So how do you do that? If you create another instance of the same name, won't it overwrite the first?

Comment: Every instance doesn't need to have a variable name associated with it. Variable names are just temporary addresses pointing to a single object. In this case, all the instances would be put in a list and you'd have to get them with an index. You really need to think of instances as things you can physically move around and variables as containers to hold certain times of things. So you put object instances into a variable, and that allows you to do things to that object. If you put another object in that variable, the initial is overwritten, but not lost if you have it stored somewhere else.

Comment: AH that actually makes a lot of sense, I shall try it! Thank you.